# Visual C++ Win32 Console application printf output on multiple lines within while loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to display data on multiple lines in my console application using printf. The following code displays the data like this:

```
Default Data=00000000 ACP Status Request=00000000 ACP VHF1 Data=00000000
```

What I need is:

```
Default Data=00000000

ACP Status Request=00000000

ACP VHF1 Data=00000000
```

When I use \n the data fills the console screen over and over again. Can anyone suggest a solution and explain why the loop is fine and the code works untill I try and goto the next line. Thanks.

```
while(!_kbhit())
{
    /*Read message records*/
    msgdefault.data = BTI429_MsgDataRd(msgdefault.addr,hCore);

    STAT_REQ.data = BTI429_MsgDataRd(STAT_REQ.addr,hCore);

    VHF1.data   = BTI429_MsgDataRd(VHF1.addr,hCore);

    /*Display values*/
    printf("\r");
    printf("Default Data=%08lX ",msgdefault.data);
    //printf("\n");
    printf("ACP Status Request=%08lX ",STAT_REQ.data);
    //printf("\n");
    printf("ACP VHF1 Data=%08lX ",VHF1.data);
}
```

Comment: put a \n at end of string e.g. `..Default Data=%08lx\n", msgdefault.data );`

Comment: Append a new line character (`\n`) to each of your outputs.

Comment: with `printf("\r");` you go to the beginning of current line. So, if you don't add `\n` you always stay on this line. If you add '\n' - new lines added on every iteration of while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need some function to jump to the start of your screen.

Read your documentation, there may be some function like [gotoxy(0,0)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d3ec2d1d-044d-441f-9472-4a284eee3e9b/alternative-to-gotoxy-) or something else.

Try searching for `System::Console::SetCursorPosition`, this may help you.

Try adding following code in the start of loop before printing anything

```
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

_COORD p;
p.X = x;
p.Y = y;

SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, p);
```

But make sure to print some empty spaces after your prints so that the remains of old prints are overwritten.